# How to build 32 Bits on Mac OS X 10.7.4 64 Bits using Maven

Tags: java, macos, maven

I have just got a Mac BookPro with os OS X Lion which has maven pre installed with the version

```
#mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.3 (r1075438; 2011-02-28 19:31:09+0200)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.6.0_31, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: tr_TR, platform encoding: MacTurkish
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.4", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

When I run a

```
mvn clean install
```

maven is somehow failing compiling. One of the fail reason is : java.lang can not found.

When I check java settings I saw that there is both 64 and 32 bit java versions.
thanks.

In the Java properties :

There are two Java instances

Java SE Apple Inc. 64 Bits 1.6.0_31-b04-415

Java SE Apple Inc. 64 Bits 1.6.0_31-b04-415

Comment: I've also had Maven 3.0.3 pre-installed on OS X when bought MacBook Pro.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment, Maven does indeed come pre-installed on OSX now. Do open up your Java Preferences and edit your question to list the Java SDK'S that it displays.

Comment: added the Java versions installed Above. But one more thing that I can't disable 64 Bit one.

Answer (score 0):

First try to write `HelloWord.java` and compile it using command line `javac HelloWord.java`.

If it works move towards maven. Check environment variable `JAVA_HOME` that is used by maven to find java. I believe it points to "wrong" java version. Fix this and try again. I hope this will work.

Comment: command line echo JAVA_HOME returns an empty result. But when I check from Java Visual VM application. I got a line : Java Home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: JAVA_HOME is not set on Macs by default.

Comment: well do you think that I should set it my self ?because mvn --version seems to see the java home ? on the output you can see it.

Comment: No, you do not need to set it. You may need to repair your Java installation - did you read my comment on your question?